# filling csv file from another csv file grouby column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, group-by

I have a csv file with 2 columns and I want to create another csv file and fill it like shown in [the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NQYP.png).

I tried:

```
xx = pd.read_csv('abc.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin-1')
for row in xx:
    ss = []
    for p in row['id']:
        ss.append(row['description'])
```

but I don't see how to continue.

Comment: use `df.description=df.description.str.split(',')` and then this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`df.groupby('id').agg(",".join).reset_index()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)